# Get Encoded Value

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, apex-code, urldecode

I have no control over domain.com. I can only give a redirect URL parameter such as below:

```
www.domain.com?retUrl=www.example.com%3Fparameter%3Dvalue
```

Right after I give retURL (www.example.com?parameter=value), I would like to retrieve the value of my parameter.

However, the problem is that browser does not accept www.example.com%3Fparameter%3Dvalue as a valid input. How should I approach this problem?

I appreciate your assistance.

**Additional info - [my motivation]**
I am using Salesforce Apex platform. I have a contact us form and Salesforce only accepts return URL. The return URL that I put is my 'Thank you' page and I want to customize my thank you page by putting my customer's name, surname, case priority details, etc.

Comment: Not sure if it is related to the issue, but have you tried URL encoding the dots in your parameter as well?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by the browser not accepting it as valid input? How does the browser behave?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the question mark, which denotes the start of parameters:

`www.domain.com/?retUrl=www.example.com%3Fparameter%3Dvalue`

Also, you should probably add the protocol portion of the URL:

`www.domain.com/?retUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%3Fparameter%3Dvalue`

Comment: You are completely, right. I have written here wrongly. I have now edited my question.